# Is there a way to use a variable in package.json?

Tags: angular, npm, gulp

Is there a way to use a variable in package.json?
so if I want to swap all angular versions I can just do it one spot, instead of 11...

```
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
    "@types/bootbox": "^4.4.30",
    "@types/immutable": "^3.8.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.41",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.32",
```

Maybe gulp to the rescue?

tx

Sean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use variables in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705195/how-can-i-use-variables-in-package-json)

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51029764/6112685

Comment: This question is different. Dependency versions in my experience cannot use config variables. Here's the closed feature request: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16320