# How can I use variables in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

There is a feature from maven I miss a lot in package.json. In maven .pom file you can define variables in parent project and use them in child project's pom files.

Is there something like this in npm? We are building modular project and I want to define dependency versions centrally and them to be used in respective package.json files.

Thanks

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Any property from `package.json` can be referenced from scripts, prefix it with `$npm_package` and adding an `_<prop>` (underscore + property) for every nested level.

Example:

```json
{ 
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Here, `name` can be access like below:

Linux/Mac: `$npm_package_name` or `${npm_package_name}`

Windows: `%npm_package_name%`

---

And, `version` can be access like below:

Linux/Mac: `$npm_package_version` or `${npm_package_version}`

Windows: `%npm_package_version%`

Comment: For Windows it should be `%npm_package_name%`.

Comment: Nothing cross-platform-ish in sight, I guess?

Comment: And how about (real word example, right now): 
`copy ../foo/web-$npm_package_version_SNAPSHOT` (I would somehow need to seperate resp. glue together the variable with the fixed portion before/thereafter, as `_SNAPSHOT` is fixed text, and the package.json version I want to use is dynamic...)

Comment: @FrankNocke I guess you can delimit the variable with curly braces (ie: `copy ../foo/web-${npm_package_version}_SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Apparently there is at least one place where this expansion does not work as I encountered `Invalid vscode engine compatibility version '^${npm_package_config_min_vscode}'`

Comment: didn't work for me at all. tried all different formats. npm -v 8.5.5

Comment: This has been broken since v7 per this RFC (https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0021-reduce-lifecycle-script-environment.md). Not called out well in the docs though

Answer (score 80):

## Reusing simple values (arguments and flags)

Define a config object in package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "config": {
    "port": "3000" 
  },
  ...
}
```

And then you can access the port value from the scrips object with `$npm_package_config_port`.

Generally, it seems possible to access any (nested) value with the prefix: `$npm_package_`.

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "config": { 
    "port": "3000"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js $npm_package_config_port"
    "start-harmony": "node --harmony app.js $npm_package_config_port"
  },
  ...
}
```

The source full article is here:

http://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/npm-scripting-configs-and-arguments.html#npm-configuration

## Reusing environment variables

On Unix-based systems, you can reuse the **value** of the environment variable with this syntax. In this case, it is the value of `MAIL-URL` env. variable.

```json
{ 
  "name": "myapp",
  "config": {
    "mail": "smtp://long-user-name:strong-password.smtp.mailtrap.io:port",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "MAIL-URL=$npm_package_config_mail meteor",
    "start-prod": "MAIL-URL=$npm_package_config_mail meteor --production",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: It allows variables usage only in "script" section of package.json unfortunately.

Answer (score 14):

I import the package.json file as a variable into my node project to get the object structure instead of using $npm_package_name.  This converts it from JSON to a JS Object

```
let package = require("./package.json");
```

[image]

Comment: Cross-platform answer. 

Answer (score 12):

On Windows, you should use `%variable_name%`. For example:

```
{
   "name": "app_name",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "custom": {
      "key": "any value"
   }
}
```

You can get it using `%npm_package_name%`, `%npm_package_version%` and `%npm_package_custom_key%`.

Answer (score 7):

A cross-platform solution, which works on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux:

```
{
    "name"   : "myapp",
    "config" : { "port" : "3000" },
    "scripts": {
        "start" : "ver && node --harmony app.js %npm_package_config_port% || node --harmony app.js $npm_package_config_port"
    },
    ...
}
```

The explanation:

The "ver" command above exists on Windows only, therefore the first part before the "||" is executed on Windows, while the part after "||" is executed on other platforms.

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice! The `sh: ver: command not found` is kinda ugly though. Now to just create a cross-platform package `is_windows` that returns false when not on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Took me a while to find my mistake:

I was running on powershell you have to use
`$env:npm_package_name` or `${env:npm_package_name}`
there to access the variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `${npm_package_variable_attribute}` to reference a variable inline with a string.

Here's an example copying a file with the `package.json` version (`${npm_package_version}`) as part of the filename:

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "upload-versioned-file": "aws s3 cp ./myfile.zip s3://my-bucket/releases/myfile-v${npm_package_version}.zip",
```

This results in the file `s3://my-bucket/releases/myfile-v1.2.0.zip`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable like this:

```
{
    "name": "javascript",
    "config": { "filename": "test" },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    
    "scripts": {
        "build": "remotion render HelloWorld out/$npm_package_config_filename.mp4"
    }
}
```

[image]