# How to set package version tag in npm package.json with $npm_package variable?

Tags: npm, package.json

Following [similar question with accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705195/how-can-i-use-variables-in-package-json) I'm trying to set a package version in a single variable and use it as a version tag for multiple packages from the same suite.

**Here's my package.json:**

```
{
...
"cdk-config": {
    "version": "1.21.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/assert": "$npm_package_cdk-config_version",
  ...
```

**The error I get:**

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "$npm_package_cdk-config_version": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I forgot to mention my npm version `6.13.6`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows?

For Linux you would use `$npm_package_cdk-config_version`

But on Windows you need to use `%npm_package_cdk-config_version%`

Quite a nuisance that they aren't the same.

Comment: Note that [`$npm_package_*` variables are no longer automatically placed in the environment since NPM v7](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/305), so this will probably break.