# Camel case matching in package.json

Tags: javascript

I need to write a task in `package.json`. It looks like this:

```js
"nyc": {
  "all": true,
  "include": [
    "src/main/**/*.tsx" // here i need to match all camelCase file names
  ]
},
```

Here`"src/main/**/*.tsx"` i need to match all camelCase titles of files.
ex: correct `"src/main/**/catBlack.tsx"`, `"src/main/**/carBlack.tsx"`
not correct `"src/main/**/cat.tsx"`, `"src/main/**/test-file.tsx"`
Who can help?

Comment: `cat` technically is in camel case. It’s in all sorts of cases.

Comment: It should be doing that. What’s nyc?

Comment: @DanielA.White, is a tool for testing with cypress https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/code-coverage

Comment: @SebastianSimon, then i need to match only this: `carWhite`, `colorGray`, but not `color`, `example`, `toy`. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to check if a string is **camelCase** using regex

```
function isCamelCased(str){
  const rgx = new RegExp('[a-z]{1,}([A-Z][a-z]{1,}){1,}$');
  return rgx.test(str);
}
```

you may want to create another function to remove the path and file extension:

```
function getFileName(str){
  let file;
   // remove the path
  file = str.split('/');
  file = file[file.length -1 ];
  // remove the extention
  return file.split('.')[0];
}
```

Test:

```
const arr =  [
    '/main/camelCase.txt',
    '/main/CamelCase.txt',
    '/camel.txt',
    '/main/camel-case.txt',
    '/main/camel2Case.txt', 
    '/main/camelCase2.txt', 
    ''
]
let file;
arr.forEach((str) => {
  file = getFileName(str);
  console.log(`${file} => ${isCamelCased(file)}`);
});
```

output:

```
"camelCase => true"
"CamelCase => true"
"camel => false"
"camel-case => false"
"camel2Case => false"
"camelCase2 => false"
" '' => false"
```

Comment: How to use this function in package.json file?

Comment: you can access _package.json_ varaibles in your code. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705195/how-can-i-use-variables-in-package-json) for further information

Comment: for me is unclear how the code should look. Could you help please?

Comment: How to change package.json?