# How to use variables in package.json dependencies?

Tags: typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I have a case where different dependencies in my package.json shall have the same version number. Ideally, I want to define the version number once and reuse this reference in the dependency definition. I know about the [possibility to define variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705195/how-can-i-use-variables-in-package-json) but they seem to only work for scripts.

Example `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  ...
  "config": {
    "ver": "2.61.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "doit": "echo version: ${npm_package_config_ver}",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dep/a": "${npm_package_config_ver}",
    "dep/b": "${npm_package_config_ver}",
    ...

  }
}
```

When I call `yarn doit`, that works and prints the version. But calling `yarn install` just tells me

```
Couldn't find any versions for "dep/a" that matches "${npm_package_config_ver}"
? Please choose a version of "dep/a" from this list: (Use arrow keys)
...
```

Am I doing something wrong or does this possibility simply not exist?

Comment: JSON is JavaScript Object Notation. It is a serialized data format and not meant to be manipulated or evaluated directly. You can hack by parsing it, checking for special sequences of characters, and then replacing them with values before re-serializing it. But once you do that, the file no longer contains the variables, so you're back to square one. In short, there's no way to intercept readers of JSON and inject values on-the-fly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mulan, that's a perfect explanation. I would mark it the answer if it was of type 'answer'. ;)