# Is it possible to run a complex multiplatform yarn build script?

Tags: node.js, bash, cmd, yarnpkg, package.json

I have the following script inside a node project's package.json.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "SOME_VAR=$(ts-node ./scripts/build/hash-check.ts) && if [ \"$SOME_VAR\" = \"true\" ]; then yarn script-1 && yarn script-2 && yarn script-3 && yarn script-4 && yarn script-5; fi",
  }
}
```

hash-check.ts ends with

```
console.log(isBooleanVar.toString());
```

This works fine for MacOS and Linux, however, when running on Windows (win32 x64), this causes the error:

```
"$SOME_VAR" was unexpected at this time.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This is due to bash `$variable` being incompatible with CMD's `%variable%` syntax.

[Yarn's package.json docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/package-json/#toc-scripts) don't contain information about writing longer scripts.

I have rewritten this for batch, but for a node project being maintained across several platforms, how are more sophisticated build scripts managed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use variables in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705195/how-can-i-use-variables-in-package-json)  See answer from Mike Flynn

Comment: @Nic3500 not really, by the time the script is running, those are essentially consts. belousov's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73192959/117507) has put me down the right track

Comment: This site is not here to rewrite code in one language for you according to code provided in another language. You'll need to research and write that yourself.

Comment: @compo where did I ask for the script in another language? "How can I update this script" I am asking about portability between bash and batch, in the context of a node project, to allow frame challenges to the question.

Comment: @compo I have now edited to show the research effort done before asking. How else do you think I should improve this question?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact thet the default shell is cmd.exe on Windows.

Try to set `"script-shell"` to your *nix shell,

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\path\to\bash.exe"
```

In case you don't have *nix shell on Windows, you can install Cygwin or Git bash.

Comment: Git bash was my first thought, oddly causes the same issue running on the console in VSCode and standalone Git bash console on win32 x64