# Sending baseUrl as a parameter in Cypress.io: How do I reference a variable as baseUrl?

Tags: cypress, package.json

I'm referencing the URL I want to use as baseUrl for some e2e-tests in several different scripts of the package.json-file and want to replace it with a variable.

This is what I've got:
In `package.json`

```json
  "prodStageUrl": "https://[name of my app].io/",
    "scripts": {
      "cy:prod:smoke": "cd ./apps/myApp && cypress run --spec './cypress/e2e/smoke/*.cy.ts' --config baseUrl=$npm_package_prodStageUrl",
    },
```

When I run `npm run cy:prod:smoke` I get the following error:

> cd ./apps/myApp && cypress run --spec './cypress/e2e/smoke/*.cy.ts' --config baseUrl=$npm_package_prodStageUrl

> An invalid configuration value was set.
> Expected e2e.baseUrl to be a fully qualified URL (starting with `http://` or `https://`).
> Instead the value was: "$npm_package_prodStageUrl"

Do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use variables in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705195/how-can-i-use-variables-in-package-json)

Comment: What you want to do is not related to cypress,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705195/how-can-i-use-variables-in-package-json